# Does a rotated polarity diagram have a special meaning on a netbook adapter?

Tags: output, adapter

I saw some other questions about replacing charger X with charger Y, so it's probably not offtopic here.

This is my original adapter:

[image]

This is the adapter that *looks* promising to be a replacement:

[image]

Everything looks just fine except the little marking for + and - part of the connector. It even **is** the same, but it's rotated which totally confuses me if you consider that the `Output` is written like that:

> OUTPUT A: 19V 2.1A    `-`-(¤-`+`    LPS
>
> OUTPUT B: 19V 2.1A    `+`-¤)-`-`    LPS

i.e. it basically looks like:

> output → `-` on the outer side, `+` on the inner side → LPS

which makes me believe the rotated marking isn't just a "mistake"(it probably doesn't matter as the meaning appears to be the same with `+`/`-` parts), but that it has some real meaning and I might screw the LPS ir even the whole machine. Am I just being stupid and the adapters are interchangeable? The connectors that go to the LPS are the same.

Comment: one is probably fake, but the parameters are the same, so they both should work

Comment: @dandavis I wonder, what did lead you to such a conclusion (fake adapter)?

Comment: if it came from the same company, they would probably reuse the same graphic template. the font is different, as is the (R), certs, etc. very inconsistent. could both be fake...

Comment: @dandavis not necessarily. Different fabric, different template. Also notice that the model isn't the same.

Comment: The one on the picture above is for Australia, you have to read the label upside down.

Comment: I wonder what's the downvote for...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both diagrams show that the center pin is positive, the outer negative.  There is no meaning in the left/right order the center versus outer pin is shown.  The two supplies are therefore compatible polarity-wise.

Comment: Great, thanks! So the rotation is probably just a matter of manufacturer's standard.